# How to check if it is chapter or chapter*?

Tags: chapters, starred-version

I'm customizing my own chapter, but I'm having problems when I want to test if it is `\chapter` or `\chapter*`.

I don't want it to have a dot when `\chapter*` is applied.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\sf\Huge\bf}{}{\dimexpr-\oddsidemargin-\hoffset-1in}
{%
\tikzstyle{background rectangle}=[fill=naranjaSaveTrack]%
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
\draw (0,0) node[anchor=east]{\color{black!70}\hspace{30pt}\thechapter.\hspace{5pt}#1};    
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Comment: You should read section **4.2 Starred Versions** of the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf): "Using sectioning commands in the starred version is strongly discouraged." However, it's possible to intervene...

Comment: IIRC, \chapter*{} creates a title formatted like it was a chapter but otherwise has no effect.  You are essentially still in the same chapter as before.

Comment: Please post a working example and not just fragments ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Small surgery on `\chapter`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {\dimexpr-\oddsidemargin-\hoffset-1in}
  {\chapterformat}

\newcommand\chapterprefix{%
  \ifchapterprefix
    \thechapter.\hspace{5pt}%
  \fi
}

\newif\ifchapterprefix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef{\chapterprefixtrue\@chapter}{\chapterprefixfalse\@schapter}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\chapterformat}[1]{%
  \tikzstyle{background rectangle}=[fill=naranjaSaveTrack]%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
  \draw (0,0) node[anchor=east]{\color{black!70}\hspace{30pt}\chapterprefix#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\colorlet{naranjaSaveTrack}{red!20} % or whatever you like

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\chapter{First}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I try your code but its not working properly, I cannot visualize the chapters Text.

Comment: @user249067 Sorry, but the example works.